# Evaluating "true" in meta-circular evaluator in Clojure

Tags: clojure, scheme, sicp, evaluator

I converted the [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs (SICP)](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1) version of the meta-circular evaluator to Clojure. The main difference (besides syntax) is the handling of the environment structure. Since you cannot use `set-car!` and `set-cdr!` in Clojure, these are implemented via an atom holding a map (copied from the code of [Greg Sexton's chapter 4 notes on GitHub](https://github.com/gregsexton/SICP-Clojure/blob/master/src/sicp/ch4.clj)).

The code of the two evaluators can be found here:

- [SICP Evaluator Scheme](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/code/ch4-mceval.scm)
- [Converted Evaluator Clojure](https://gist.github.com/erooijak/1dd7e9cba93bc8e4e3255ac8cd48ba9f)

The main procedure `eval` does a case analysis and then decides what to do next with the expression `exp` in the environment `env`:

```
(defn eval [exp env]
  (cond (self-evaluating? exp) exp
        (variable? exp) (lookup-variable-value exp env)
        (quoted? exp) (text-of-quotation exp)
        (assignment? exp) (eval-assignment exp env)
        (definition? exp) (eval-definition exp env)
        (if? exp) (eval-if exp env)
        (lambda? exp) (make-procedure (lambda-parameters exp) 
                                      (lambda-body exp)
                                      env)
        (begin? exp) (eval-sequence (begin-actions exp) env)
        (cond? exp) (eval (cond->if exp) env)
        (application? exp) (apply (eval (operator exp) env)
                                  (list-of-values (operands exp) env))
        :else (throw (Throwable. (str "Unknown expression type \"" exp "\" -- EVAL")))))
```

When interacting with the Clojure evaluator you can do things like:

> ;;; Eval input:
>   (defn hello-string hello)
>   ;;; Eval value:
>   < environment map >
>   ;;; Eval input:
>   hello-string
>   ;;; Eval value:
>   hello

This shows new frames can be stored in and retrieved from the environment.

When the environment is setup initially, `true` and `false` are explicitly added:

```
(defn setup-environment []
  (let [initial-env
        (extend-environment primitive-procedure-names
                            primitive-procedure-objects
                            the-empty-environment)]
    (define-variable! 'true true initial-env)
    (define-variable! 'false false initial-env)
    initial-env))
```

But when an if-expression is entered, the code fails because it cannot find "true". (Same happens if you just evaluate `true`, which in the Scheme version evaluates to `#t`).

> ;;; Eval input:
>   (if true hello-string "hi")
>   CompilerException java.lang.Throwable: Unknown expression type "true" -- 
>   EVAL, compiling:(/home/erooijak/clojure/scheme-interpreter/scheme-
>   evaluator.clj:314:1)
> *(I would expect this to be evaluated to "hello")*

Since `eval-if` works properly in the Scheme version (and does not work if `true` and `false` are not added to `setup-environment`, it looks like `eval` does not interpret `true` as something that needs to be looked up in the environment in the Clojure version.

Unfortunately, I do not see exactly how this looking-up happens in the Scheme version and why it does not happen in the Clojure version.

I hope someone can steer me in the right direction on why evaluating `true` works in the Scheme, but not in the Clojure implementation of the meta-circular evaluator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are using Clojure's built-in reader, rather than implementing it yourself based on string inputs. `true` and `false` do not read as symbols, but rather as booleans, and then probably your `variable?` function doesn't return true for booleans.

Relatedly, you write `(define-variable! 'true true initial-env)`, as if you believe `'true` and `true` are different values; they are the same, just as `'6` and `6` are the same.

Comment: This helped me. Easiest solution was to make true and false self-evaluating.